# Wordpress website only showing text 'Hello World' upon visiting

Tags: wordpress, godaddy

I've been trying to fix this issue for a long time, but whenever I go to my WORDPRESS website it just shows a plain 'Hello World' text despite me having downloaded themes and media for the website.

I've hosted the website with GoDaddy. What could be the problem here? [Here's](https://svroyal.com) the page

What might be the problem?

I tried contacting the hosting support, and they told me that it was the DNS, so I followed their instructions and waited for a few days, and it still didn't get fixed. The wordpress dashboard says that I'm using the correct theme, but whenever I turn on the editor, it just shows 'Hello World'.

Comment: Did you add a "hello world" file to your site at some point?  If so, it sounds like its still there and interfering with WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

The website which is serving your website is "Apache".   When I go to https://svroyal.com I get the "hello world" page, however when I go to https://svroyal.com/(anything) it comes up with a Wordpress powered web page.

Apache has a directive called DirectoryIndex - which most likely has a list of files it will assume as the default file (if it exists, and if no filename is specified after the domain name).

**You likely have a file with "hello world" written in the default file** which is being preferred by Apache over the index.php file which apache needs.  (My *guess* - I can't be certain without more access to the site - is you have a file index.html in the root directory of your website which needs to be deleted.   If its not index.html there will be another similar file which needs to be deleted - If you can use FTP or similar to look at your web root directory - often its public_html - and sort it by file size, look for a small file - probably about 12 bytes - and if it contains the words "hello world" rename it to something like "index.html.back" and things should start working properly)